# Randomly chunk variables to groups of a certain number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a large pandas dataframe in which I am attempting to randomly chunk objects into groups of a certain number. For example, I am attempting to chunk the below `object`s into groups of 3. However, groups must be from the same `type`. Here's a toy dataset:

```
type     object       index

ball     soccer       1
ball     soccer       2
ball     basket       1
ball     bouncy       1
ball     tennis       1
ball     tennis       2
chair    office       1
chair    office       2
chair    office       3
chair    lounge       1
chair    dining       1
chair    dining       2
...      ...          ...
```

Desired output:

```
type     object       index    group

ball     soccer       1        ball_1
ball     soccer       2        ball_1
ball     basket       1        ball_1
ball     bouncy       1        ball_1
ball     tennis       1        ball_2
ball     tennis       2        ball_2
chair    office       1        chair_1
chair    office       2        chair_1
chair    office       3        chair_1
chair    lounge       1        chair_1
chair    dining       1        chair_1
chair    dining       2        chair_1
...      ...          ...      ...
```

So here, the group `ball_1` contains 3 unique objects from the same type: `soccer`, `basket`, and `bouncy`. The remainder object goes into group `ball_2` which only has 1 object. Since the dataframe is so large, I'm hoping for a long list of groups that contain 3 objects and one group that contains the remainder objects (anything less than 3).

Again, while my example only contains a few objects, I'm hoping for the objects to be *randomly* sorted into groups of 3. (My real dataset will contain many more balls and chairs.)

This seemed helpful, but I haven't figured out how to apply it yet: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need split for each `N` values per groups by `type` is possible use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), integer divide and add `1`, last add column `type` in [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
N = 3
g = df.groupby('type')['object'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) // N + 1

df['group'] = df['type'].str.cat(g.astype(str), '_')
print (df)
     type  object  index    group
0    ball  soccer      1   ball_1
1    ball  soccer      2   ball_1
2    ball  basket      1   ball_1
3    ball  bouncy      1   ball_1
4    ball  tennis      1   ball_2
5    ball  tennis      2   ball_2
6   chair  office      1  chair_1
7   chair  office      2  chair_1
8   chair  office      3  chair_1
9   chair  lounge      1  chair_1
10  chair  dining      1  chair_1
```

If need also some randomize values add [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
N = 3
df = df.sample(frac=1)
g = df.groupby('type')['object'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) // N + 1

df['group'] = df['type'].str.cat(g.astype(str), '_')
print (df)
     type  object  index    group
10  chair  dining      1  chair_1
8   chair  office      3  chair_1
2    ball  basket      1   ball_1
1    ball  soccer      2   ball_1
7   chair  office      2  chair_1
0    ball  soccer      1   ball_1
9   chair  lounge      1  chair_1
4    ball  tennis      1   ball_1
6   chair  office      1  chair_1
3    ball  bouncy      1   ball_2
5    ball  tennis      2   ball_1
```